# scrape data from "div" nested with vba

Tags: excel, nested, scrape, vba

I'm not an expert in scraping, but thanks to the help of another forum I was able to get data from a site, my problem that they could not solve is to scrape data from "div" nested in other "div" as in figure:[scrape nested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeLPj.jpg)

I would like to put in an excel sheet ,using vba, in every cell every single data circled in red,

thanks to a user of another site I managed to get this script but it does not pick up the nested data

```
Sub Scraping_xScores()

   Dim objIE As Object

   Dim itemEle As Object
   Dim desc As String, pt1 As String, pt2 As String, price As String
   Dim y As Integer

   Sheets("Foglio1").Activate
   Range("A:AA").ClearContents

   Set objIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
   objIE.Visible = True

   objIE.navigate "http://www.xscores.com/soccer/leagueresults/england/premier_league/2017-2018/r/0"
   Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

   y = 1

   For Each itemEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("score_row match_line e_true")

       'desc = itemEle.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).innerText
       Sheets("Foglio1").Range("A" & y).Value = itemEle.Children(0).innerText
       'put text of 2nd 'td' in col B
        Sheets("Foglio1").Range("B" & y).Value = itemEle.Children(2).innerText
        'put text of 3rd 'td' in col C
        Sheets("Foglio1").Range("C" & y).NumberFormat = "@"
        Sheets("Foglio1").Range("C" & y).Value = itemEle.Children(3).innerText

        'put text of 4th 'td' in col D
        Sheets("Foglio1").Range("D" & y).NumberFormat = "@"
        Sheets("Foglio1").Range("D" & y).Value = itemEle.Children(4).innerText
       y = y + 1
   Next

   objIE.Quit
   Set objIE = Nothing

   Cells.Select
   With Selection
       .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
       .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
       .WrapText = False
       .Orientation = 0
       .AddIndent = False
       .IndentLevel = 0
       .ShrinkToFit = False
       .ReadingOrder = xlContext
       .MergeCells = False
   End With
   Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

this is an excellent solution and I would like to separate the "div" in single cells such as date, time, home team, guest team, yellow cards, red cards, first half result, second half result.
my current situation is this
[my current situation is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bcFA.jpg)

I would like to get to this
[I would like to get to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqkKK.jpg)

I'm near to close to the solution but I need help, please

thanks

Comment: have you tried working with any of the many existing examples?

Comment: there is nothing suitable for my needs

Comment: Out of the "whole internet", there's *nothing* about scraping from nested div's?  Wow.

Comment: I'm not an expert in scraping can you explain yourself better?

Comment: You are not getting all the scores but rather every other row. Was that intentional?